# Composer.json problems

Tags: php, json, symfony

when i try to do composer update or a require i got lot of problems about stability and comptability that i cant fix. There is a way that i can fix that ?

When i try to do what composer said to me i just add some new problems i dont why such errors.

This is what i get :

Problem 1

```
- Installation request for friendsofsymfony/message-bundle 1.3.0 -> satisfia
ble by friendsofsymfony/message-bundle[v1.3.0].
- friendsofsymfony/message-bundle v1.3.0 requires doctrine/collections ^1.3
-> satisfiable by doctrine/collections[1.5.x-dev, 1.6.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.4.0, 
v1.
5.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Problem 2

```
- Installation request for petkopara/multi-search-bundle ^1.0 -> satisfiable
by petkopara/multi-search-bundle[v1.0.0].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.16
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.3.15
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.15
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.14
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.13
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.12
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.11
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.9
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.8
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.7
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.6
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.4
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.3
- Installation request for incenteev/composer-parameter-handler 2.0 -> satis
fiable by incenteev/composer-parameter-handler[v2.0.0].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.2
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.36|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.37|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.38|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.39|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.40|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.41|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.42|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.36|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.37|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.38|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.39|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.40|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.41|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.8.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml 2.0.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml 2.0.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml 2.0.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml 2.0.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.0.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- don't install symfony/yaml v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
- petkopara/multi-search-bundle v1.0.0 requires symfony/symfony ~2.8|~3.0 ->
satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.15, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, 
v3.3.
12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.16, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, 
v3.3.7, v
3.3.8, v3.3.9].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.1
```

And this is my composer.json :

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "adesigns/calendar-bundle": "1.1.1",
    "doctrine/collections": "1.2.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.6.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/message-bundle": "1.3.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "2.0",
    "javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle": "1.17.9",
    "petkopara/multi-search-bundle": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: These kinds of updates can be a real mess.  What I would do is to start a fresh project and install the various dependencies one by one.  With luck you will end up with a working composer.json file to use as a reference.

Comment: And what about my current project ?

Comment: Good to see you got it working.  To answer your last comment, just replace the old composer.json with the new one.  Then I usually delete the vendor directory completely and do an install.  You do want to be a bit careful with just fixing one line.  It may appear to work but you could be masking other issues that might come back and bite you.  For example the monolog bundle really should be "^3.1.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is `incenteev/composer-parameter-handler` in v2.0, which requires `symfony/yaml` in v2.0. If you try to install `symfony/symfony` in v3.3, this tries to install `symfony/yaml` in v3.3 - so, this won't work. You could try to install `incenteev/composer-parameter-handler` in v2.1.2, this might work with Symfony 3

Comment: Thanks for your reply ive already solved this the same way you said

Comment: And just for informations it was the only problem, after solving this, no more errors

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following scenario

package A needs Package B with version 1.0

Now you are trying to install another Package C which requires Package B with version 2,

Now this obviously breaks Package A, since it require Version 1 of Package B,

**So in turn composer says it can't install package C, since it breaks the current dependencies**

Comment: I see ! But this is just a normal update i dont want to install a new package .So what could i do to solve this

Comment: during the update, some package requires new version of certain packages, that's the problem here, so you can try to update each package separately. especially the ones which are showing in the composer errors, then try for a full update

Comment: "Don't forget to tip your waiter by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer if this is useful. :o)